# What is the use of generating getters and setters in a class annotated with @Entity (Hibernate)?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

What is the use of generating getters and setters in a class annotated with @Entity (Hibernate)?
When do they get invoked?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
//other getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Just to add to this, use Lombok for your getters and setters.  Just annotate your class with `@Getter` and `@Setter` and you don't have to fill your class with these accessor methods.  You can also use `@Data`, which includes equals and hashcode, but don't use `@Data` on your entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Hibernate uses `public` getters and setters to access entity's attributes, which is considered to be a common approach.

However, it is not strictly required by Hibernate. If your fields are `public`, then you can tell Hibernate to access those fields directly (through `access` option). In other hand, having `private`, `default` or `protected` fields/getters/setters, Hibernate is able to deal with them too (through refection, I think).

From [Hibernate reference:](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/mappingGuide/en-US/html/ch02.html)

> **2.1.3. Declare getters and setters for persistent attributes**

> Standard, portable JPA essentially requires this. Otherwise your model would
> violate the requirement quoted above in regards to accessing the
> entity persistent state fields directly from outside the entity
> itself.
>
> Although Hibernate does not require it, it is recommended to follow
> JavaBean conventions by defining getters and setters for you entities
> persistent attributes. You can still tell Hibernate to directly access
> the entity's fields.
>
> Attributes (whether fields or getters/setters) need not be declared
> public. Hibernate can deal with attributes declared with public,
> protected, package or private visibility. Again, if wanting to use
> runtime proxy generation for lazy loading the visibility for the
> getter/setter should be at least package visibility.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as your fields are private then you need getters and setters to access them outside of the entity class.